# UserVoice widget hide tab

Tags: javascript, uservoice

Is there a way to hide the UserVoice tab?

Inspecting the UserVoice object in firebug I see the functions

```
hidePopupWidget()
showPopupWidget()
showTab()
```

but no `hideTab()`

I would like to programmatically control the show and hide of the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just setting tab element to css `display:none;` e.g. `$("#uvTab").hide();`

Answer (score 1):

You can just click 'edit widget' on UserVoice page and choose 'use my own link'
After a few minutes the tab will disappear on the site.